# Sed to replace tab with Control-A in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

Working with data and trying to convert a tab-delimited to control-a in a shell script.  Using command-line, I would represent control-a by doing the following sequence, 'control-v, control-a'.

Here is my code in a .sh:

```
echo "tab    delimited     query     here" | sed 's/    /'\001'/g' > $OUTPUT_FILE
```

However, this doesn't work.  I've also tried the following:

```
 '\x001'
 x1
 '\x1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tr` here:

```
echo $'tab\tdelimited\tquery\there' | tr '\t' $'\x01'
```

To demonstrate that it has been replaced:

```
echo $'tab\tdelimited\tquery\there' | tr '\t' $'\x01' | cat -vte
```

**Output:**

```
tab^Adelimited^Aquery^Ahere$
```

**`sed` alternative:**

```
echo $'tab\tdelimited\tquery\there' | sed $'s/\t/\x01/g'
```

**`awk` alternative:**

```
echo $'tab\tdelimited\tquery\there' | awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\x01' '{$1=$1} 1'
```

Comment: What's that `$` doing in `tr '\t' $'\x01'`?

Comment: Words  of  the  form `$'string'`  are  treated specially.  The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

Comment: Yes it is, OP can also use: `tr '\t' '^A'` where `^A` is `ctrl-V-A` typed together

Comment: Okay, got it, thanks.  Learn something new every day.  (Me, I would have used `tr '\011' '\001'`.)

Comment: these appears to be working well.  however, i'm running it over 1M rows and getting some strange splits.  Thinking it due to additional tabs in my data

Comment: All the tabs will be replaced by above commands. You might be having some other strange characters e.g. DOS line ending or control/invisible characters.